# Arduino timeout communicating with programmer error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino, микроконтроллеры

При загрузке простейшего блинка или hello world на Arduino Mega2560, получаю следующие ошибки:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
The uploader process failed
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

**Плата новая, еще ни одной программы на ней не запускал.** Подключение идет при помощи USB к COM3 порту.

Пробовал Arduino IDE и переустановку\удаление драйверов платы. В чем может быть проблема?

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 с расширением vMicro для разработки под Arduino.

Comment: А Arduino Mega2560 оригинальная или китайская подделка?

Comment: @Unick Оригинал

Comment: а если попробовать через arduino-ide с нормальным avr-gcc? или ручками avrdude'ом?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Через arduino IDE тоже пробовал. Абсолютно то же самое :/ Не могу понять в чем проблема здесь...

Comment: @4L3X возможно это конечно время написать претензию тому у кого ты брал платку, но прежде покажи полный вызов (включая вызов) `avrdude` в коммандной строке arduino, когда ты пытаешься залить скетч....

Comment: [https://pp.userapi.com/c841233/v841233031/74c02/0lcCrNWwmTs.jpg](https://pp.userapi.com/c841233/v841233031/74c02/0lcCrNWwmTs.jpg)

Здесь лог. Вместе с компиляцией и самой ошибкой. Компилирую через Visual Studio 2017, в Arduino IDE тот же самый лог, если включить режим Verbose

Comment: @4L3X, всё равно не хватает собственно вызова avrdude... я не уверен как можно достоверно его получить в VS, но arduino должен его выдавать... на будущее, стоит упоминать тому кому отвечаешь через собаку всегда....

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73962/discussion-between-fat-zer-and-4l3x).

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, знаю, забыл в прошлом сообщении)
Вот команда сборки, как я понимаю:
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino9\bin\avrdude "-CC:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino9/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega2560 -cwiring "-PCOM3" -b115200 -D "-Uflash:w:C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\VMBuilds\MUSEUM~1\MEGA_A~1\Debug/MuseumApp.ino.hex:i"

Comment: гммм... на unix'овый взгляд всё в порядке... разве что `-cstk500v2` не хватает... но судя по всему именно из-за этого и возникают ошибки

Comment: подразумевая конечно, что COM правильно указан.... ЕМНИП первые 4 (0—3) зарезервированы для навивных портов....

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Я пробовал указывать 5й порт, вываливалась совсем другая ошибка о том, что поддерживается только 3 порт...

Comment: @4L3X, воспроизвёл ошибку — у меня появляется при указании неверного последовательного порта... Посмотри в настройках драйвера, там должна быть возможность задать на какой порт ардуина подвешена...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, При указании другого порта выдает:
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: Неверный дескриптор.

Comment: Попробуйте применить другой кабель usb или обратиться в поддержку магазина.